# Relationship with the same data type of multiple entities

Tags: jhipster

There are three entities: A, B, and C in the same data type. That is they are the same from an application logic point of view. Now, another entity D has a many-to-one relationship with three entities which is treated as the same data type.

In Hibernate or Spring Data JPA, you can model a many-to-one relationship between entity D and entities A, B, and C using a single association, since they are treated as the same data type from the application logic point of view. To do this, you can use inheritance and create a common superclass for entities A, B, and C. Then, entity D can have a many-to-one relationship with this common superclass. Here's a step-by-step guide on how to design this relationship:

1. Create a Common Superclass:
   Define a common superclass that encapsulates the common attributes and behavior of entities A, B, and C. This superclass should be annotated with @MappedSuperclass. This annotation indicates that this class is not an entity itself but serves as a base class for other entities.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class CommonEntity {
    // Common fields and methods
}
```

2. Create Entities A, B, and C:
   Create entities A, B, and C that extend the CommonEntity superclass. Each entity can have its specific attributes and annotations as needed.

```
@Entity
public class EntityA extends CommonEntity {
    // Entity A-specific attributes
}

@Entity
public class EntityB extends CommonEntity {
    // Entity B-specific attributes
}

@Entity
public class EntityC extends CommonEntity {
    // Entity C-specific attributes
}
```

3. Create Entity D:
   Create entity D, which has a many-to-one relationship with the common superclass (CommonEntity).

```
@Entity
public class EntityD {
    @ManyToOne
    private CommonEntity commonEntity;

    // Other attributes and methods for Entity D
}
```

4. Configure Hibernate:
   Make sure to configure Hibernate to recognize these entities, create the appropriate database tables, and manage the relationships. You can use @EntityScan in your Spring Boot application to specify the base package(s) where your entities are located.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.entities")
public class YourApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

With this setup, I have established a many-to-one relationship between entity D and the common superclass (CommonEntity), allowing you to reference entities A, B, and C through a single association. You can now use Spring Data JPA repositories and Hibernate to persist and query these entities as needed in your application.

To design the many-to-one relationship in the context of JHipster, one approach is to leave out the relationship definition in the JDL. And create the CommonEntity and change the entity classes accordingly.

Any better approach?